# Blog/CMS software with editing style like Stack Exchange

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

Are there any pieces of content creation software for making a blog that support an editing style like Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow?  Or magic combinations of Wordpress plugins that offer the same?

I have been updating a Wordpress blog lately and found the turnaround time for content creation and editing is much worse than for Stack Overflow posts.  Part of this has to do with being original compositions rather than riffing off a question.  But part of it is the software.

I am looking for CMS/blog software that has an overall editing experience similar to Stack Overflow.

The most important features I'm looking for:

- Inline editing
- (mostly) Real-time preview on the same page are all important features for speeding up data entry.
- Markdown support (with inline and block-level code support)
- Syntax hilighting

The features I must maintain from my self-hosted Wordpress:

- Somewhat popular/supported software, with extensibility support
- Self hostable
- Will work with MySql

Wordpress has plugins for all these, but they don't necessarily work together.  For example I've found a few markdown-on-save plugins, but I doubt those have a chance of ever supporting inline editing or real time previews.  Also the most popular syntax hilighting plugins don't support inline code blocks, and I doubt previews would work with other syntax hilighting methods.

If I get a wiki/web page content creation system along with it, or somehow integrate this into GitHub (with all the features I requested) I'll accept those as side benefits.

Comment: Anonymous downvoters here too?  Is this off topic?

Comment: perhaps you're asking for way too much.

Answer (score 0):

http://ikiwiki.info has

- real-time preview being adapted from StackOveflow, cf. http://ikiwiki.info/todo/mdwn_preview/, http://ikiwiki.info/forum/wmd_editor_double_preview/;
- [markdown support](http://ikiwiki.info/features/#index3h2);
- [syntax highlighting](http://ikiwiki.info/todo/syntax_highlighting/) done with [a supported plugin](http://ikiwiki.info/plugins/highlight/);

and is

- [somewhat popular](http://ikiwiki.info/ikiwikiusers/), with [extensibility support](http://ikiwiki.info/plugins/);
- is [self-hostable](http://ikiwiki.info/setup/);
- as for SQL, there might be a plugin for it, or you may [write](http://ikiwiki.info/plugins/write/) one.

Answer (score 0):

I think Drupal fits your bill. You can use Drupal to create website/blog/CMS that caters to all your requirements. It is free! Easy to use! www.drupal.org

Comment: please elaborate if one need to use plugins/modules to achieve the goal. And if yes what are those?